# how to query current data postgress/mysql in grafana

Tags: mysql, postgresql, grafana

need help, i need queries mysql/postgres for current date / today only.

current i am using

```
select to_char(SUM(amount), 'FM9,999,999,999,999') AS TOTAL from tabeltrx where destination_bank_code = '111' and created_date > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' and status='Completed';
```

but when i know this query result will be last 1 day its mean when current 8am it will be sum 8am last day until 8 am today.

my expected only sum amount today date 00 - 08 am.

how about this queries , is it queries only last 5 minutes?

```
SELECT $__timeGroupAlias(date_created,5m,0),sum(amount)/100 as trx_testing FROM `tbl` WHERE sid='xxx' and $__timeFilter(date_created) and ACTION='CONFIRM'
```

how the queries in grafana ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work in both MySQL and Postgres:

... AND created_date >= CURRENT_DATE AND ...